# Optimize function in r with the boundary value

Tags: r, function, optimization

I have the following function and want find $x$ satisfying this requirement.

$$\frac{X^{2}(1.5)^{2}\exp{1.5X^{2}}}{2} < 1$$

I wrote the following `r` function.

```
f <- function(X) 0.5*X^2 * 1.5^2 * exp(X*1.5) < 1
optimize(f, c(0, 1))
```

But it is giving me an error. I want to find the value of `X` satisfying the requirement. Thank you for the help.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `< 1`; I think what is happening is not what you intended.  The output of `f` is either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: @Suren, I want to find the value of `X` which satisfying `0.5*X^2 * 1.5^2 * exp(X*1.5) < 1`.

Comment: So, the minimum for `f` would be zero, right. Then you want to find the value  of `X` for which `f` is zero. Which would be `-Inf`. If you use the  `optimize` function, it would give you the lower value of the interval. Just use `f <- function(X) 0.5*X^2 * 1.5^2 * exp(X*1.5)`.

Comment: @Suren, I have one more question. How to maximize with respect to `X` ? Thanks.

Comment: The optimize function has an option `maximum = FALSE` by default.

Comment: @Suren, `f <- function(X) 0.5*X^2 * 1.017^2 * exp(X*1.017)
optimize(f, c(0, 1), maximum = TRUE)` Then, I found `X = 0.9999339`. After I substitute in the given function, then I have value `0.5*(0.9999339)^2 * 1.017^2 * exp((0.9999339)*1.017) = 1.429561` which is greater than `1`. How can I find the value `X` which produce the value less than `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we define ff as

```
ff <- function(X) 0.5*X^2 * 1.5^2 * exp(X*1.5)
```

then graphing it

```
curve(ff)
```

we see that ff(0) = 0 and ff(x) is monotonically increasing in x.  The largest value of x for which ff(x) <= 1 can be calculated as the solution to ff(x) = 1 which occurs at the minimum of g:

```
g <- function(x) (ff(x) - 1)^2
optimize(g, c(0, 1))
```

giving:

```
$minimum
[1] 0.6008074

$objective
[1] 1.058761e-09
```

Thus any value of x between 0 and 0.6008074 gives a value of ff in the closed interval [0, 1].

```
# create graph
curve(ff)
opt <- optimize(g, c(0, 1))
abline(h = 0:1)
abline(v = c(0, opt$minimum))
```

[image: screenshot]